# 80s Book About Kid Werewolf

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

Looking for a kid's book (maybe young adult, but probably juvenile) about a kid who discovered he was a werewolf. At the end of the book, he comes home after being a werewolf all night. He is naked and has to get a house key from under the welcome mat. His mom then comes in and reveals that she is a werewolf too. Please help!

Comment: ^_^ I know you've been here a while, but have you gone through the list at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info to see if you can add anything more?